# What's the best way to pass an array from jade to node js

Tags: node.js, pug

I am currently building a very simple cms. So you start of with just a textbox with a "**more**" button right next to it and when you press it, it inserts a newly created textbox.

so i want to be able to get all these values from each textbox created and post it to the server

I have tried looking it up but found nothing atall ! urghh can someone please help out :)

this is my code so far

**app.js**

```
router.post('/addname', function(req, res) {

// connect to the results collection
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('names');

    // Get form values. 
    var content = req.body.names;

    // Submit to the DB
    collection.insert({
        "content": content
    }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            // If it failed, return error
            res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            // And forward to success page
            res.redirect("/");
        }
    });
```

**jade**

```
form(action='addname' method="post")
   div#mynames()
          button#addmore(style="margin-left:-220px;" onClick="addtextbox") Add more
          input#names(name='names' placeholder='@', type='text')
```

**jquery**

```
function addTexbox(){

    $("#names").append('<br><input placeholder="@" type="text" style="border-radius: 15px; border: none;" />');
    // contains all name input element
    var allname = $("#names:input");
    console.log(allTags[0].value);
}
```

so far it can generates the new textbox if the button is pressed

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it should be `input#names(name='names[0]' ...` for it to be just a single element of the array `names` which will be passed to the server as `req.body.names`.

```
form(action='addname' method="post")
   div#mynames()
          button#addmore(style="margin-left:-220px;" onClick="addtextbox") Add more
          input#names(name='names[0]' placeholder='@', type='text')
```

Then when you add new inputs, just add them with incremented array counters

```
var inputCounter = 1;
function addTexbox(){    
    $("#names").append('<br><input name="names['+ inputCounter++ +']">');
}
```